# count number http response

Tags: arrays, shell

Iam basic with shell script, I want to count from log file like this:

```
192.168.1.4 - - [16/May/2019:01:18:07 +0000] "GET /api/v1/tests HTTP/1.1" 200 422 "-" "okhttp/3.11.0"
192.168.1.3 - - [16/May/2019:01:54:24 +0000] "POST /api/v1/test HTTP/1.1" 201 138 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

and the output should be:

```
number, count
200, 1
201, 1
```

I`ve tried with wc command but did not find solution

```
wc -l or wc -w
```

the error did not find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uniq` can work in your case like below :

```
egrep -o '200|201' <filename> |sort|uniq -c
```

To use array, you can do something like this :

```
my_array=(200 201)
for i in ${my_array[*]};do egrep -o ${i} <filename> |sort|uniq -c ;done;
```

Comment: but this case the date with 2019 will count

Comment: @johanesbrain It shouldn't as we are using -o, --only-matching (Prints only the matching part of the lines ). I just tried and it's only matching 200 and 201. You can also use -w, --word-regexp which will look for an exact match.

Comment: do you have array script with this?

Comment: @johanesbrain updated the answer to include the array to perform the task.

Comment: @Pacifist 2019 contains 201, so your script counts it wrong

Comment: @Ferrybig 2019 does contain 201 but we are using -o which only look for 201. It will not match to 2019.